# Know g++ Version of Code blocks in Windows

Tags: c++, c++11

I am solving questions on Interviewstreet.com. They said they use C++ version g++ 4.6.3,C0x mode.
I am writing code on code blocks. So i want to know which version iam using in code blocks is it in C0x mode or C11 mode??

I have tried using g++ --version i got g++ TDM-2 mingw32   4.4.1.Can u tell me where i can get this kind of information.
what is the difference between C++ 0x and C++11??

Comment: So you're using version 4.4.1. C++0x was what people called c++11 before they knew which year it was going to be finalised. Because of this, g++ still uses `--std=c++0x` to specify that you want the new features. Edit: Also, you are talking about C11 mode and C++11 mode. I presume you only mean to talk about c++, but you should know there was also a new c standard in 2011.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to update the version of g++ to 4.6.3 (or later) if you want to use c++11 features. See [this question and it's answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version) on how to do it for deb linux.

Then you'll have to pass `--std=c++0x` to the compiler in options. You should be able to easily find them in codeblocks.

> what is the difference between C++ 0x and C++11??

c++0x is a synonym for c++11.

Comment: Since mingw is mentioned, I'm guessing this is on Windows, not Linux.

Comment: @BoBTFish and that's relevant how?

Answer (score 0):

The command:

```
g++ --version
```

gives you the version of your g++ or mingw compiler. Since you got `g++ TDM-2 mingw32 4.4.1` then your version is `4.4.1`. If you want to use version `4.6.3` as in that web site, then you would have to update.

It wouldn't hurt to use a newer than `4.6.3` version of mingw, so please see [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-inst/mingw-get-inst-20120426/) for the latest version. This page offers an windows installer for mingw.

After installation, you would have to configure CodeBlocks to use the newly installed compiler by looking into `Compiler and debugger settings` -> `Toolchain executables` tab and setting the paths for the compiler-related executables to the new ones.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**:

[Here](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Code%20Blocks%20Compiler%20Setup) is a small tutorial/example of what the CodeBlocks settings look like.