# Using new standard of C++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, c++11, g++

The site [Interview Street](https://www.interviewstreet.com/) says that they use "g++ 4.6.1, C++0x Mode". As I know the C++11 was called C++0x before official release. So does that mean they provide unstable or unofficial support for C++11?

Can I safely use C++11 features while coding on "Interview Street"?

Comment: What makes you think you can safely use C++11 features in any environment? http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Comment: Standard library comes with your compiler.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597254/know-g-version-of-code-blocks-in-windows quick search found this...

Comment: @nightcracker it depends on the feature.

Comment: @Caribou : I have already seen that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend GCC 4.7 for better support. But you can use some C++11 features in 4.6 too. Here's the list of them:

http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/cxx0x_status.html

Answer (score 1):

c++0x is a synonym for c++11 so you should be fine.

But there are some features you can use and others that you cannot. Refer here:

http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/cxx0x_status.html

Comment: Not really, it depends on the feature. You could say "you'll have to update to version 4.7" too. 4.7 supports some features not supported on 4.6.3.

Comment: edited to correct my error. thanks